# Finding the Solution out of N possibilities

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, optimization, search-algorithms

Suppose there are 10 (4x4) matrices, where the elements in each matrix are dependent on one variable ($\theta$) non-linearly. All the matrices are independent of each other, so there are 10 $\theta$s ($\theta _{1}$, $\theta _{2}$, $\theta _{3}$, $\theta _{4}$,......). 
 Now, let the input matrix be A, and an output matrix is B. The variables of each matrix ($\theta$) should be varied so that, multiplying all the ten matrices with A, we should get the output matrix B. The value of $\theta$ varies from 0 to 2$\pi$.
 *I cant write this in the form of $AX_{i}=B$ format because while multiplying the matrices, I have to do an operation where the non-diagonal terms are put to zero keeping only the diagonal terms. 
 (A here is the input matrix and suppose $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4}......X_{10}$ are the variable matrices which depend on $\theta$.  Now suppose I have multiplied A with $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ Then whatever the matrix I get after multiplying A with $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ i need to do a operation, where it makes all the non-diagonal terms zero, keeping only the diagonal terms. Now suppose after this operation I get C. Then, I again multiply $X_{3}$ and $X_{4}$ with C to get a matrix (lets say D) where I have to perform the same operation where it makes the non-diagonal elements zero keeping the diagonal terms. In this way i will multiply all the $X_{i}$ matrices.)*   
 I am using the **brute force method** to find the correct solution of 10 variables, but it takes a lot of time. 
 **What should be the efficient way to solve this problem? Or what is the standard procedure to do this kind of problem.**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Do the elements of the matrices depend linearly on the variable? Let's say that the $10$ matrices are $X_1, \dots, X_{10}$. What prevents you from solving, for each $i$, the system of equations $A X_i =B$?. The system consists of 4 equations, one for each of the $4$ entries of the matrix. If you have a single variable per matrix, this amounts to solving a single non-trivial equation  and checking that the solution satisfies the other ones.

Comment: Yeah, this is true. But this does not apply to my problem as I can't write in this $AX_{i}$ form. Because while multiplying the matrix, there is also an operation where I need to put all the non-diagonal elements to zero, keeping only the diagonal terms. Also, the elements of the matrices depend non-linearly on the variable.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I am quantifying efficiency by the amount of time it will take to solve the problem. Or rather I want to know what are the standard procedures to deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, there are 10 (4x4) matrices. Now, after multiplying two matrices with A, I need to do that operation on the resultant matrix which I get after multiplying the two matrices.  Then again, after multiplying four such matrices, I need to do that operation. The main thing is that I cannot write this in  $AX_{i}=B$ format.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami i have edited the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130028/discussion-between-saptarshi-biswas-and-inuyasha-yagami).